# Upgrade Remote Desktop in Vista to support multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I am using Windows 7 and I was able to remote desktop into another Windows 7 machine and use multiple monitors.

*Is there a way to do the same when connecting to a Windows Vista machine?*  Is there an update available anywhere for Windows Vista or do I have to upgrade it to Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

there appears to be limited support for spanning on wWindow Vista machines - see here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125234108/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session.aspx)